# copy folder path to listbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

I manage to drag and drop multiple folder path to listbox, is it possible to do this using copy/paste, for example, you copy multiple folder on windows explorer then paste those folder path on the listbox using contextmenu, shortcut keys, or a button..

```
    Private Sub lstFolder_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles lstFolder.DragDrop           
        Dim directories As String() = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())          
        For Each folder As String In From folders In directories Where Directory.Exists(folders)
            If Not lstFolder.Items.Contains(folder.ToString()) Then
                lstFolder.Items.Add(folder.ToString())
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub lstFolder_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles lstFolder.DragEnter          
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, False) = True Then          
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All
        End If
    End Sub
```

---

@ Vignesh Kumar

works great, one question how about, copying the folder location from a document file or from address bar, here is my code so far.

```
    Dim directories As String() = CType(Clipboard.GetData(Windows.Forms.DataFormats.FileDrop), String())
    'loop through the string array, check if folder exist then adding each folder to the ListBox
    For Each folder As String In From folders In directories Where Directory.Exists(folders)
        If Not lstFolder.Items.Contains(folder.ToString()) Then
            lstFolder.Items.Add(folder.ToString())
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use `Clipboard` object

```
string[] files = (string[])Clipboard.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.FileDrop);
```

Files or/and folders will be in this string array.